# Reduce multidimensional array in processing to drop empty odd rows

Tags: multidimensional-array, processing, reduce

I have the following problem, I imported a file .csv into a 2d array called csv.

This has null entries in each odd row, therefore just even rows, starting from 0 (0, 2, 4, ... 606) are filled with data relevant for me

so, the size of the 2d array is 609, 560 and they come from printing csv.length and csv[1].length

I need to have a file whose size is 304x561, and I call it csv2.

However, the following code gives me an error

```java
String rows[] = loadStrings("cit2.txt");
String [][] csv; // initialize csv file
String [][] csv2; // initialize reduced csv file
int csvWidth=0;

//calculate max width of csv file
for (int i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  String [] columns = split(rows[i],'\t'); 
  if (columns.length>csvWidth){
    csvWidth=columns.length;
  }
}


//create csv array based on # of rows and columns in csv file
csv = new String [rows.length][csvWidth];

//parse values into 2d array
for (int i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  String [] temp = new String [rows.length];
  //strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  temp= split(rows[i], '\t');
  for (int j=0; j < temp.length; j++){
   csv[i][j]=temp[j];
  }
}

//test
println(csv[604][0]);
println(csv.length);
println(csv[0].length);

int row = csv.length;
println(((row-1)/2));
int newrow = 0;

int col = csv[0].length;
//int row = csv.length;


csv2 = new String [((row-1)/2)-1][col];

for (int c=0; c <csv[0].length; c++)
{
  for(int r=0; r<(csv.length)-1; r = r+2)
  {
    String temp = csv[r][c]; 
    newrow = newrow +1; 
    csv2[newrow][c]= temp;
  }
}
```

any idea?

Comment: What's the error? Also, can you give us a sample cit2.txt file?

Comment: sounds like it might be a `\r` `\n` issue with the way the csv file was saved on various operating systems